# Open drawer by app icon

Tags: android

I would like to open and close the drawer by clicking the app icon. However, the app stopped when the activity is creating when `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` and `getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` is add, and when these lines are deleted, the app stopped when the drawer is opened by sliding. Also, the app icon did not shown. Please help.

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener {

private ExpandableListView drawerList;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

private final Context context = this;

private ListView LV;
private ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

private ImageView logout;
private ImageView end;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    find();

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    setListener();
    setAdapter();
    prepareListData();
    setList();
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

private void setListener() {
    drawerList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if (groupPosition == 0)
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(context, ViewActivity.class));
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });
    LV.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    logout.setOnClickListener(this);
    end.setOnClickListener(this);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private void find() {
    LV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    logout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logout);
    end = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.end);
}

private void setAdapter() {
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            text.setTextSize(34);
            return view;
        }
    };
    aa.add("Roster");
    LV.setAdapter(aa);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
    if (LV.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Roster"))
        startActivity(new Intent(context, ViewActivity.class));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == logout.getId()) {
        AuthenticationController.getAuthenticationController().Logout();
        startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class));
    } else
        onBackPressed();    
}

private void setList() {
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    drawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    listDataHeader.add("Social Service Management System");
    listDataHeader.add("App Group A");
    listDataHeader.add("App Group B");

    List<String> SSMS = new ArrayList<String>();
    SSMS.add("Roster");
    List<String> appA = new ArrayList<String>();
    appA.add("App Group A Item");
    List<String> appB = new ArrayList<String>();
    appB.add("App Group B Item");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), SSMS);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), appA);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), appB);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
    homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(homeIntent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest following the developer's site about Navigation Drawer here:
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

According to `getActionBar()` remove it, extend ActionBarActivity and use this code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```